# Handling React onToggle event

Tags: reactjs

I am working on the below snippet, and I'd like to find out why I am not able to bind `onToggle` event with button component. I am getting 'onToggle' is not defined on compiling.

In the main container (Content) I have:

```
class Content extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      user: dataService.User
    }
  }
  onTogglePane(){
    var node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.wrapper);
    node.classList.toggle('toggled');
  }
onSignOut() {
dataService.Logout((result) => {
  this.setState({
    user: null
  })
});
}
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Header 
      onClick = {this.onSignOut}
      onToggle ={this.onTogglePane}
    />
  
  </div>
 )
 }
}
```

In the Button.js I have button component as:

```
import React from 'react';

const Button = ({ text, styleClass, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={e => onClick(e)}
     onToggle={e => onToggle(e)}
      className={`btn ${styleClass}`}
    >
      {text}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

and finally in the Header.js I have

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'components/Button';
class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-default hk-navbar fixed-top">
        <p className="navbar-brand tk-brand">App</p>
        <Button
          text={[<i class="icon icon-logout"></i>,  " Sign Out"]}
          onClick = {(e) => this.props.onClick(e)}
          styleClass = 'btn-control'
        />
          <Button
          text={[<i class="icon icon-logout"></i>,  " Full Screen"]}
          onToggle = {(e) => this.props.onToggle(e)}
          styleClass = 'btn-control'
        />
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/components/Button.js
  Line 8:  'onToggle' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: try `this.props.onToggle(e)` inside `button.js`

Comment: Button.js is a functional component so this.props won’t work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you are missing onToggle which you are passing it to Button component.

Below Button component code would fix the issue

```
 import React from 'react';

 const Button = ({ text, styleClass, onClick, onToggle }) =>    {
    return (
       <button
        type="button"
       onClick={onClick ? onClick: null}
       onToggle={onToggle ? onToggle: null}
       className={`btn ${styleClass}`}
      >
        {text}
     </button>
     );
  };

  export default Button;
```

Comment: Thanks a lots Think-Twice now I am not getting the compile error, but when I click the button I am getting `TypeError: _onClick is not a function` error on line 7 of button.js for `onClick={e => onClick(e)}`

Comment: Because you are not passing onClick to Button component of onToggle like wise you are not passing onToggle to Button component of onClick and that why u get the error

Comment: Ok I got lost! but I was able to use onClick event for onSignOut()

Comment: Thanks, again the `Sign Out` button is working but the `Full Screen` is do noting with no error.